# Proof of $b^{1/n} \rightarrow 1$ with Bernoulli's Inequality

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

this is my rough proof of the said statement. I hope you can help me verify it.

We want to proof that if $b > 0$ then $b^{1/n} \rightarrow 1$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Let $b = (1+a)$, where $a > 0$.

We have $(1 + a)^{1/n} \leq (1 + \frac{a}{n})$ because of Bernoulli's Inequality in case $\frac{1}{n} \leq 1$.

Thus for any $\epsilon > 0$,

$|(1+a)^{1/n} - 1|  = |b -1|\leq \frac{a}{n} < \epsilon$ for $n \geq N$. $\square$

Comment: This proof won't work if $b<1$ - since then you would have $a<0$

Comment: Can you give me a good suggestion to improve it?

Comment: I think just replacing $\frac an$ with $ \mid \frac an \mid $ in the last line should work, as Bernoulli's inequality works for $a \ge -1$